# How do I install GCC 4.7.1 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gcc

It so happens that I hit a bug in Ubuntu's GCC 4.7.0, which has been fixed in later versions of GCC; I believe it's already fixed in 4.7.1.

1. I can always download the source, compile and install it, but wouldn't it conflict with Ubuntu's package management?
2. There's a ["Toolchain test builds" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/test), but it seems to only contain 4.7.0 for Ubuntu 12.04.

What should I do to install GCC without disrupting my system?

Comment: Do the first, but don't use `make install` use `checkinstall` to create a .deb package and install it so the package manager is aware of it.

Comment: There's an answer-less question here on AskUbuntu about `checkinstall` tracking half of the filesystem, making the created package quite useless. Then again, maybe the poster was missing something with the prefix or suffix.

Comment: Well I've used it before, with Inkscape and with Media Explorer (an HTPC software) and they're causing no trouble in my system.

Comment: You'll have to agree Inkscape is not the same as a compiler which contains OpenMP, ld and stdc++... :) In addition, it seems building GCC for Ubuntu is not free of pitfalls. I used http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/ and it was pretty smooth, but the result fails to link some programs.